# Слово со значением "имеющий форму"

Tags: лексика

Как с помощью прилагательного выразить яркую, четкую форму предмета? Например, если речь заходит о чем-либо выступающем из-за ткани (студенческий билет, паспорт, другая фигурная вещь более сложного профиля), что он выступает правильной фигурой.

Формальный, форматный, форменный? Все узкоспециально.

Значение искомого слова "имеющий форму".

Comment: Выступал правильно/прямоугольно очерченный предмет?

Comment: Александр, для справки скажу, что под правильной формой человек понимает правильный многоугольник, то есть тот, у которого все стороны равны. Квадрат, например, равносторонний треугольник и т.д.

Comment: Правильно очерченным (это шире) бывает и "овал лица"; в вопросе  фигурируют "сложные профили".

Comment: Нет, в вопросе не фигурируют сложные профили. Речь идет о предмете, обращающим на себя внимание своей формой, будь то правильно очерченной, будь то затейливой.

Comment: А для чего упомянута _другая фигурная вещь более **сложного профиля**_?

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, "рельефный", "конгревный"?

Comment: Конгревный с каким существительным употребимо? С предметом?

Comment: Это синоним слова "рельефный" - штамп, рисунок, тиснение...

Comment: Узкопрофессиональные слова не стоит употреблять за пределами их узкой профессиональной области применения.

Comment: Фигуристый. Или (особенно если сложный профиль;) фигуристая.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы вообще отошёл от идеи подобрать однокоренное слово к "форме" и предлагаю употребить каждому знакомое прилагательное "геометрический".